# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'BranchQuickChange'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've been on this error for a while and the `ienumerable` object is blocking can someone pls help me the error is in the description.

HTML:

```
@model IEnumerable<DatabaseDAL.Models.WAGTripHdr>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("select#BranchQuickChange").change(function () {
    var branchName = $("select#BranchQuickChange option:selected").text();
    alert(branchName);
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("QuickBranchChange", "TripSheets")?branchName=' + branchName;
});
</script>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4" style="margin-top: 15px">
    @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator") || User.IsInRole("SuperUser"))
    {
        <strong>Quick Switch</strong> @Html.DropDownList("BranchQuickChange",ViewBag.CompanyList as SelectList)
    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 {
        List<WAGBranch> listWagBranch = WAGBranchRepository.GetAllBranches(CompanyEnum.WAG).OrderBy(i => i.BRName).ToList();
        List<string> listCompany = new List<string>();
        foreach (WAGBranch branch in listWagBranch)
        {
            listCompany.Add(branch.BRName); // + " - " + branch.Branch);
        }
        //listCompany.Insert(0, "WAG HEAD OFFICE - WAG");
        if ((string)selected == "") selected = null;
        ViewBag.CompanyList = new SelectList(listCompany, selected);
    }
```

Model:

```
 [TableNameAttribute("WAGTripHdr")]
public class WAGTripHdr : SQLSelectUpdateInsertHelper
{

    public string DebName { get; set; }

}
```

Waiting for some advices.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually occurs when the collection passed to `DropDownListFor` is null. As a fallback, the helper tries to find the options in the `ViewBag` under a member named after the property, i.e. `ViewBag.BranchQuickChange`. When it fails to find anything usable there, as well, it gives up and you get the exception you reference.

That said, it appears you *are* in fact setting `ViewBag.CompanyList` in your action. Additionally, it is being set to a `SelectList` instance, so casting it back to `SelectList` in the view as you're doing should materialize the value. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps a different action than the one you've posted here is being loaded. In particular, if you have GET and POST versions of this action, make sure that *both* set `ViewBag.CompanyList`. It's possible you only added that line to one and not the other.